# Angular4 warning using interface export

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interface, angular-cli

I need to export several interface with other stuff from a single file :

```
import * as P from 'library';
export interface item extends P.itemParent {}
export interface group extends P.groupParent {}
export type event = P.EventType;
export class items extends P.DataSetItem{}
export class groups extends P.DataSetGroup{}
```

I get warnings like this one uppon build :

```
WARNING in ./src/app/common/t/directive/t.directive.ts
```

The project use :

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.4.5",
"typescript": "~2.3.3"
```

I checked other posts and google, but didn't found any clear solution to this issue

Any idea how could I correct this?

> EDIT :

Complete error log

```
118:50-68 "export 'VisTimelineOptions' was not found in '../base/base-vis'
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors
```

Comment: Can you include the message from the warning? There should be a message that tells you what the problem is and what line it is on.

Comment: I updated the question but this is not really relevant. base-vis is the file containning all the exports, VisTimelineOptions is one of them